"X-WP-Nonce" Header was not mentioned in Thunder Client
i create a little react application where i want to caught some date from the api.
Fetch Data:
try {
    const response = await fetch(uri, {
        method: 'POST',
        credentials: 'include',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'X-WP-Nonce': window.studio_w_obj.nonce,
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(formData),
    })

    if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error(`HTTP error! status: ${response.status}`)
    }

    onCreateEvent(await response.json())
} catch (error) {
    setError(error.message)
}

Route:
register_rest_route($this->namespace, '/schedules', [
    'methods' => \WP_REST_Server::READABLE,
    'callback' => [$this, 'get_schedules'],
    'permission_callback' => '__return_true',
]);

function get_schedules(\WP_REST_Request $request) {
    $nonce = $request->get_header('X-WP-Nonce');

    if (!wp_verify_nonce($nonce, 'wp_rest')) {
        return new WP_Error('rest_cookie_invalid_nonce', __('Invalid Nonce'), array('status' => 403));
    }

    $results = $this->wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $this->table_name", OBJECT);
    return new \WP_REST_Response($results, 200);
}

If I start the build and test the application directly in the WordPress backend, I receive all the data. However, if I try to retrieve the data via Thunder Client (or Postman), I always receive the following message:
{
  "code": "rest_cookie_invalid_nonce",
  "message": "Cookie check failed",
  "data": {
    "status": 403
  }
}

This are my settings in Thunderclient:

I noticed that if I want to output the header $nonce = $request->get_header('X-WP-Nonce'); it remains empty in Thunder Client. In WordPress I get my value.
Which setting do I have to pay attention to in Thunder Client?
What I have already added:

.htaccess

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE"
  Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "X-WP-Nonce, Content-Type, Authorization"
</IfModule>


PHP

function add_cors_http_header() {
  header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:3000");
  header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT");
  header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Authorization");
}
add_action('init', 'add_cors_http_header');


WP_DEUP

define('WP_DEBUG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);

I don't get any error messages.
My application run on http://localhost:3000. Did anyone knows which setting is missing?
